# How to Skip Spring Login Page

Tags: spring-security, siteminder

I am using siteminder for authentication but currently for development purpose I am faking the URL attributes like SM_USER through fiddler tool. I am able to get the attribute in my class where I have Implemented my custom methods to get the user Permissions from DB. Everything works fine,at the end it redirects to the Spring Security Login Page.Below is my code snippet...

```
     <http pattern="/pages/UnAuthorized.jsf*" security="none"/>
     <http pattern="/pages/Logout.jsf*" security="none"/>
     <http pattern="/pages/SessionTimeout.jsf*" security="none"/>
     <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="fullyAuthenticated" />
<custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter" />
<logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/pages/Logout.jsf" />
</http>

   <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" >  
    </authentication-provider>     
   </authentication-manager> 

    <bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  
        class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">  
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="UserPermissionsProcessor"/>  
</bean>

<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"  ref="userDetailsServiceWrapper">
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried using entry-point-ref as suggested it in one of the post but didn't worked for me.

Comment: When working with Spring security I've always found that switching on the debug logging gives lots of useful information about what's happening.

Comment: i debugged it till method loadUserByUserName(String userId) method end... I am not sure where it goes after that...

Comment: Alex Thanks a lot!! I turned my debug on for Security and I found the issue.It was with the user isAccountNonLocked default value being false. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. It's always worked for me because the logging is so detailed. It provides a step by step analysis of what is happening and why.

Answer (score 0):

Is it creating the Authentication Object? If yes set that in SecurityContextHolder as follows.

> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

If authentication object is not present, then the below line fails,

and obviously you will be redirected to the login page.